# Get the Id of current Canvas when mouse click

Tags: jquery, html, canvas, getelementbyid

How can I get the current ID of the canvas, when I clicked on it. In my Html page, I have two canvas:

```
<div>
<canvas id='canvas1' style="width: 740px; height: 420px"></canvas>
</div>
<div>
<canvas id='canvas2' style="width: 740px; height: 420px"></canvas>
</div>
```

When I clicked on one of the canvas, how can I get the ID of it. I tried like this:

```
$('#canvas1').click(function(){ 
    alert('Clicked on Canvas1');
});

$('#canvas2').click(function(){ 
    alert('Clicked on Canvas2');
});
```

But, no alert was displayed while clicking on the canvas..
Any Ideas??
Thanks in advance..

Comment: Idea: This js code goes before your `canvas` elements and you don't use `ready` event.

Comment: use dom ready event to know all elements loaded.

Comment: Thanks for reply..I'm not using ready event. One of my function I called that click event.

Answer (score 1):

use it with domready

```
$(function(){
$('#canvas1').click(function(){ 
    alert('Clicked on Canvas1');
});

$('#canvas2').click(function(){ 
    alert('Clicked on Canvas2');
});
});
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/wh3ax/)

Comment: I did it under if conditio..like this..if (drawObject.currentState == DrawState.Completed) {
                        $('#canvas1').click(function () {
                            alert('Clicked on Canvas1');
                        });

                        $('#canvas2').click(function () {
                            alert('Clicked on Canvas2');
                        });
                                 
                }

Comment: what ever u posted working fine dude... but Why my code was not firing..??

Comment: you are assigning the click events before elements load, so the events  not attaching to the elements.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to assign the click bindings after the document is ready, for example like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#canvas1').click(function(){ 
    alert('Clicked on Canvas1');
  });
});
```

Another option to know the id would be that you give your canvas an additional class.
Then you bind the click event on the class and then read the id from the event object like this:

```
$(".canvasclass").click( function(eventObject) {
  alert(eventObject.target.id);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I used the event.currentTarget.id to get the dom ID of the canvas.  I don't know how robust it may be - I will ask others to weigh in.  And, I am admittedly a novice to JavaScript.

Start by binding the click event handler to each canvas in question.  Then, interrogate the event object to get the currentTarget.id and that is the dom id of the canvas that was clicked.

```
$(window).load(function() {
    canvas1 = document.getElementById("canvas1");
    canvas1.addEventListener("mousedown", getPosition, false);
    canvas2 = document.getElementById("canvas1");
    canvas2.addEventListener("mousedown", getPosition, false);
}

function getPosition(event) {
    var x = event.clientX;
    var y = event.clientY;
    var canvas_id = event.currentTarget.id
    var canvas = document.getElementById(canvas_id);
    // you can now execute canvas methods on the canvas clicked on
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you can make your event binding common...

Markup.

```
<div>
    <canvas id='canvas1' style="width: 740px; height: 420px; background: red;"></canvas>
</div>
<div>
    <canvas id='canvas2' style="width: 740px; height: 420px; background: blue;"></canvas>
</div>
```

JS code.

```
$(function() {
    $("canvas").click(function(e) {
        alert($(this).attr("id"));
    });
});
```